# Why is my component returning an empty Object in ReactJS?

Tags: json, reactjs, object, react-router, components

I am having an issue, with passing data from my JSON file to a quiz component that I am attempting to create. So far I have had luck passing the data through a simple JSON file that I have stored in my Src folder. However when I try to access my much larger file which is located in my public folder, nothing is returned. Instead of returning an object filled with "current question" and "current options", it returns a blank object.

It would be more helpful if the app showed some kind of error, but because I have no idea what is causing this, I am at a loss at the moment.

This is the main file which is being used to generate questions, I utilise this component to pass properties from my JSON file.

```
class Play extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            questions: this.props.questions,
            currentQuestion: {},
            nextQuestion: {},
            previousQuestion: {},
            answer: "",
            currentQuestionIndex: 0,
        }
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        const {questions, currentQuestion, nextQuestion, previousQuestion} = this.state;
        this.displayQuestions(questions,currentQuestion, nextQuestion,previousQuestion)
    }
    displayQuestions = (questions = this.state.questions, currentQuestion, nextQuestion, previousQuestion) => {
        let { currentQuestionIndex } = this.state;
        if(!IsEmpty(this.state.questions)){
            questions = this.state.questions;
            currentQuestion =  questions[currentQuestionIndex];
            nextQuestion = questions[currentQuestionIndex + 1];
            previousQuestion = questions[currentQuestionIndex - 1];
            const answer = currentQuestion.answer;
            this.setState({ 
                currentQuestion, 
                nextQuestion,
                previousQuestion,
                answer
            });
        }
    }

    render(){
        const {currentQuestion} = this.state;
        return(
            <React.Fragment>
                <Container>
                    <H5> {currentQuestion.question}</H5>
                    <OptionsContainer>
                        <ul> 
                            {!!currentQuestion.options && currentQuestion.options.map((option) =>
                                <p className = "option"> {option.option}</p>
                            )}
                        </ul>
                    </OptionsContainer>
                </Container>
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
}
```

This is how I am using the Play component to dynamicaly pass the data from the JSON file I have below.

```
<Play questions = {this.props.questions}/>
```

This is a snipped from the component that dynamicaly renders the urls and places each set of data in a seperate component.

```
    <Route path = {`${url}/:topicId`} render = {
        ({ match }) =>
        <TopicHeaderCard {...coreTopics.find(topic => topic.id === match.params.topicId)}/>}
    />
```

A snippet of my JSON file that is used to get the quiz information (very basic at the moment)

```
 "questions": [
                {
                    "question": "How tall is your fridge?",
                    "options": [
                        {
                            "option": "6 feet"
                        },
                        {
                            "option": "12 feet"
                        },
                        {
                            "option": "3 feet"
                        },
                        {
                            "option": "1 foot"
                        }
                    ]
                }
```

Thanks In advance, all help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that props take times to load before passed. So instead of componentDidMount, you should try componentDidupdate so that when props update the data you can use it.

I'm not sure the code below in gonna works, just give it a try and adapt to your preference.

```
class Play extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            questions: [],
            currentQuestion: {},
            nextQuestion: {},
            previousQuestion: {},
            answer: "",
            currentQuestionIndex: 0,
            initComplete: false
        }
    }
    componentDidUpdate(){
        const {questions} = this.props;
        if(!IsEmpty(questions) && !initComplete){
            currentQuestion =  questions[currentQuestionIndex];
            nextQuestion = questions[currentQuestionIndex + 1];
            previousQuestion = questions[currentQuestionIndex - 1];
            const answer = currentQuestion.answer;
            this.setState({
                questions,
                currentQuestion, 
                nextQuestion,
                previousQuestion,
                answer,
                initComplete = true
            });
    }

    render(){
        const {currentQuestion} = this.state;
        return(
            <React.Fragment>
                <Container>
                    <H5> {currentQuestion.question}</H5>
                    <OptionsContainer>
                        <ul> 
                            {!!currentQuestion.options && currentQuestion.options.map((option) =>
                                <p className = "option"> {option.option}</p>
                            )}
                        </ul>
                    </OptionsContainer>
                </Container>
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
}
```